# Stacking Plots with same x-axis but different y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 3 variables that I want plotted that have different y-axis but the same dates. I want the plots stacked on top of each other, but with just the date at the very bottom plot and the y-axis titles next to each variable.

Here is the table of values
[image]

```
    jump_vel_tracking <- ggplot(Jump_tibble, aes(date, daily_max_vel)) + geom_point(color = 'red3') + 
                      geom_line() +
                    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 3.5, to = 3.8, by = 0.1), limits = c(3.5, 3.8)) +
                      labs(x = 'Date', y = 'Peak Velocity') # title = "NCM Squat Jump - 20 kg Peak Velocity")  
jump_vel_tracking

jump_power_tracking <- ggplot(Jump_tibble, aes(date, daily_peak_power)) +
                        geom_point( color = 'navyblue') + geom_line() +
                        scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq (from = 1350, to = 1470, by = 40), 
                                           limits = c(1350,1470)) +
                        labs(x = 'Date', y = 'Peak Power')# title = "NCM Squat Jump - 20 kg Peak Power")
jump_power_tracking

jump_mRFD_tracking <-ggplot(Jump_tibble, aes(date, daily_peakmRFD)) +
                        geom_point(color = 'green') + geom_line(size = 0.2) + 
                        scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 3800, to = 4600, by = 200), 
                                           limits = c(3800,4600)) +
                          labs(x = 'Date', y = 'Peak mRFD', title = "NCM Squat Jump - 20 kg Peak mRFD")  
jump_mRFD_tracking

plots <- grid.arrange(jump_power_tracking,jump_vel_tracking, jump_mRFD_tracking, ncol = 1)
```

when I plot with grid.arrange it gives me the x labels and the titles of each graph which I don't want[image]

Comment: Have you looked at facets? Particularly facet_wrap

Comment: Yes but whenever I try to use facet_wrap it only reads in my max velocity variable

Comment: You probably need to restructure the data (pivot_longer?) So that you have a variable to group by